# Selected option shouldn't appear in spinner dropdown list

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a `Spinner` that is used to populate some choices. My `Spinner` acts as a filter to the `ListView` below it.

The `Spinner` looks something like this:

****Option 2**** (selected)

****Option 1****

****Option 2****

****Option 3****

****Option 4****

Is there a way that i can hide the selected item from the dropdown list, like in this case Option 2 which is selected shouldn't appear in the dropdown list

Comment: what you have tried so far for achieve this?

Comment: Instead of hiding it,why don't you just change it's color?

Comment: And what you have tried yet, thought about any approach.

Answer (score 0):

Android Spinner not providing any built in implementation which satisfy your requirement.

You need to modify the data set of your Spinner Adapter when user select any item.

Save the selected Item in separate variable and remove it from data set of your Spinner adapter. When user select any other item, you need to add already selected item to data set, save the newly selected item in global variable and remove it from data set of Spinner adapter.